# Javascript function that calculates the sum of all numbers (using a faster run time performance)

Tags: javascript

i need a different way of writing the  addUpTo(n) function . which as a better performance  or calculate faster  than the function i have below

A JavaScript function that calculates the sum of all numbers from 1 up to (and including) some number n.

```
function addUpTo(n){
    let total = 0;
    for(let i =1; i<=n; i++){
        total +=i;
    }
    return total;
}
```

need a faster way of writing this function which is far better than this

Comment: "need a faster way of writing this function" : may I ask why ? Now that you already wrote it, you'll never need to write again. You can save it as a library script, or copy paste it in the projects you need. Or do you mean that the function executes faster ? Then, can you be more specific in how this one performs poorly in your scenario (what is your requirement, what is range of inputs possible, how this current implementation fails to satisfy your need, etc..)

Comment: Check out [this page](https://scotch.io/courses/the-ultimate-guide-to-javascript-algorithms/range-sum) for some cool ideas

Comment: This is the stereotypical problem among stereotypical problems... I can't believe a 30 second search won't give 1000 answers to this.

Comment: the current implementation is slower when it comes  to timing try this on ur browser console    function addUpTo(n){
//     let total = 0;
//     for(let i =1; i<=n; i++){
//         total +=i;
//     }
//     return total;
// }

// console.log(addUpTo(4))

//another way

function addUpTo(n){
   return n * (n+1)/2; 
}

console.log(addUpTo(4))    the 2nd function calculates faster than the 1st

Answer (score 4):

The sum of the numbers from `1+2+...+N` can be expressed as the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number): `sum = N*(N+1)/2`.

Therefore, you can write:

```
function addUpTo(n) {
    return n * (n+1) / 2;
}
```

This will out-perform the method in the question since it removes the loop from the calculation.

---

See snippet for simple performance analysis

```js
// loop method
function addUpTo(n) {
  let total = 0;
  for(let i =1; i<=n; i++){
    total += i;
  }
  return total;
}

// formula method
function calcSum(n) { return n * (n+1) / 2; }

let t0 = performance.now();
let s1 = addUpTo(1000000);
let t1 = performance.now();

let t2 = performance.now();
let s2 = calcSum(1000000);
let t3 = performance.now();

console.log(`addUpTo calculated ${s1} in: ${t1-t0} ms`);
console.log(`calcSum calculated ${s2} in: ${t3-t2} ms`);
```

Comment: I just answered the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first natural numbers `1,2,...,N` can be expressed as `N*(N+1)/2`.

[image]

Thus yielding:

```
const addUpTo = n => n * (n + 1) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addUpTo(n){
     let total = 0;
     for(let i =1; i<=n; i++){
         total +=i;
     }
     return total;
 }

 console.log(addUpTo(4))

//another way

function addUpTo(n){
   return n * (n+1)/2; 
}

console.log(addUpTo(4))         

let t1 = performance.now()

addUpTo(1000000000);
let t2 = performance.now()

console.log(`Time Elapsed ${(t2 - t1)/1000} seconds.`)
```

if try this on your browser console you discover the 2nd function is faster than the  first